# Difference between this. and this->

Tags: c++, operators, this, operator-keyword

Is there any difference between `this.` and `this->` ?

If yes, please elaborate the differences ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it out?

Comment: I know the question is for beginners only, but it is.

Comment: The major difference is that `this.` isn't C++.

Answer (score 3):

One will compile, one won't. `this` is a pointer, and you can't apply `.` to a pointer. Use `->` to access members of the object it points to.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you meant `(*this).` instead of `this.` in this case there is no difference, because for pointers `a->b` is defined as `(*(a)).b`.